# What is the China equivalent timezone in PHP?

Tags: php, timezone

What is the China equivalent timezone in PHP from [this list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)?

Comment: OK, which of those listed cities lie in mainland China…?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_China#IANA_time_zone_database

Comment: I think Asia/Shanghai is good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IANA time zone identifier for China is `Asia/Shanghai`.

PHP (and many others) use IANA time zones.